# accept only english character in form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to accept only English character in a text box form validation in codeigniter.
Is there any built form validation method for this or should I use my own validation function for implementing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule you need is alpha. You could do something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text','required|alpha');
```

To ensure that what is entered contains only alphabetical values.

See the [rule reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) on the codeigniter documentation.

Comment: if its text and space prefer alpha_space

Answer (score 0):

tried to find the solution for 3 days .... above one cannot pass space, underscore, hyphen etc etc etc ....

so what i did to filter and pass only English characters:
(works for me fine .... maybe stupid, but i tried so many options! none working but only this one)

```
$this->load->helper('text');
    $yourText = ascii_to_entities($yourText,true);  

if (strpos($yourText,'&#') !== false) {
    echo 'use English only';
}else {
    echo 'all good';
}
```